# Drupal - Replace the home page

Tags: drupal

Hi
Anyway to stop people browsing the Drupal home page and redirect to my specific html page?

Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have specific HTML page that it is on the server and doesn't generated from Drupal, the most easy way is to use Drupal goto.

How to do it? open your template.php and search for page_preprocess function it should look like that:

```
YOURTHEME_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if( drupal_is_front_page()) {
      drupal_goto('yoursite.com/yourpage.html')
  }
}
```

change YOURTHEME to your theme name and clear the cache.

The real Question why should you use static HTML file for your homepage? I would create some article or view for homepage and change it as I like with theming... It is much easier than any other alternative.

Comment: I am using the theme of fusion http://drupal.org/project/fusion, but I can't find the keywords in template.php, could you advise me how to hack this file?

Comment: It is no 'hack' template.php is designed to include preprocess functions.
As I said before The real Question is why should you use static HTML file for your homepage?

Comment: Because the module of flowplayer and swf tool don't provide enough support for the streaming, so I need to customize a html that implement my request.

Comment: So why don't you create page-front.tpl.php and put whatever code that you want to put in your front page? much better thing to do, at least I think so....

Comment: What to include in the page-front.tpl.php? Can I have some refereece? Thanks you

Comment: copy page.tpl.php into page-front.tpl.php, clear Drupal caache and put the HTML that you want in age-front.tpl.php.

Answer (score 5):

For Drupal 7 you need to use page--front.tpl.php

If your theme doesn't have a page.tpl.php that you can copy, then copy it from your base theme if you are using one or:

```
modules/system/page.tpl.php
```

This should be placed in your custom theme folder in (assuming this is not a multisite):

```
sites/all/themes/my_theme
```

I tend to structure my themes as follows:

```
my_theme.info
templates/html.tpl.php
templates/page/page--front.tpl.php
templates/node/node.tpl.php
templates/block/block.tpl.php
css/style.css
```

But it doesn't really matter where it is, it will be picked up after a cache clear.

Comment: Can't see the file, in which fold should be the file ?