# How to set up a Drupal 7 landing page?

Tags: drupal-7, customization, drupal-theming

**Landing page :** A landing page is a very first page of a website. For example, if you go to http://www.google.co.in/ you can see a page that specific page you view for the main domain is called a landing page. The very first page of the website.

Likewise, I would like to setup a page that should render or show up once an end user hits an URL http://www.website.com and can able to see a page, where the page should have a layout designed by me and using theme files of drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to understand what exactly you are asking.

This may help answer your question: [Drupal - Replace the home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231291/drupal-replace-the-home-page)

Comment: I would wonder about your understanding on a simple landing page. I tried page--front.tpl.php and it's working anyways I have to create menus and pages to check whether they are using page.tpl.php. Now the page--front.tpl.php used by the home page only. Let me know how to create a menu as a parent item, where the menu link should show the name of menu in breadcrumb. For example, it is currently showing as Home>>About us while I click on about us menu link. I wanted it to show as About us>>title of page content.